# How can I use a git repository as an AWS Lambda source within Terraform?

Tags: git, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm working within [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io) to configure an AWS Lambda - and initially, I've had the JS file that is the entirety of the lambda function within my Terraform directory:

```
data "archive_file" "auth_requests" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/auth_requests/index.js"
  output_path = "${path.module}/auth_requests.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "auth_requests" {
  function_name    = "auth_requests"
  filename         = "${data.archive_file.auth_requests.output_path}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.auth_requests.arn}"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.auth_requests.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
}
```

However, it's clear that the Lambda function should get its own git repo, rather than living within our broader Terraform repo. Is there a way to use Terraform to source files from a git repo (and then brought into the generated archive)?

I could define the lambda's GitHub repo [as a resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/github/r/repository.html), but then what would be the next steps for getting it cloned/updated so the `archive_file` can refer to it? Or can a Terraform module be repurposed for something like this?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want the Lambda function's repo to deal with deploying it?

Comment: Currently we've got all of our infrastructure in one repo - there's some overlapping access between apps/projects. Certainly, if we split that off more distinctly, then it could very well make sense to do what you suggest.

Comment: I find it a useful model to have app specific infrastructure in the app's repo and allow the CI for the repo deploy things but I guess not everyone is happy with that. If you didn't want to do that you could have the Lambda repo be responsible for pushing it to S3 and then have your infrastructure repo be responsible for deploying it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR making the lambda function's repo aware of all the versions/regions/environments/etc that it needs to deploy to, and when, would be duplicating a lot of stuff from the infra repo and tf definitions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a Github repository to store your JS function, you can make use of the [Github Content API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) to download a zip of the repo using `curl`:

```
curl -L -o <output zip filename> https://<github repo url>/zipball/master
```

You can achieve this in Terraform using the `External` provider instead of the `Archive` provider:

```
data "external" "download_function" {
  program = ["curl", "-L", "-o", 
"${path.module}/auth_requests.zip", "${var.github_repo_url}"]
}
```

The downside is that you now have an external dependency (curl).

Comment: The external program described by the program attribute must implement a specific protocol for interacting with Terraform, as follows: The program must then produce a valid JSON object on stdout, which will be used to populate the result attribute exported to the rest of the Terraform configuration.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Terraform for your infrastructure setup & maintenance, but then manage deploys directly through Github Actions.

Your Terraform setup will just bootstrap an initial version of the function code, with subsequent updates coming straight from GitHub. Use the [ignore_changes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes) meta-argument so that Terraform doesn't get mad about the drift.

### `terraform-repo/lambda.tf` will set up the lambda but ignore changes from deploy:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = ...
  role          = ...
  handler       = ...

  # just include a basic "hello world, this is a stub" handler in here
  filename  = '${module}/lambda_stub.zip' 

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      'last_modified',
      'source_code_hash'
    ]
  }
}
```

### `Code-repo/.github/workflows/deploy_lambda.yml` will actually do the deploy:

```yaml
name: Deploy Lambda

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy_zip:
    name: deploy lambda function
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Zip up the code
        run: zip -r build.zip ./src

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Update Lambda code
        run: aws lambda update-function-code --function-name=${{ secrets.LAMBDA_NAME }} --zip-file=fileb://build.zip
```

This way you can deploy quickly without doing an entire `terraform plan` cycle, and you can still use terraform to update and maintain your infrastructure.